# Google Calendar - Populating website table with next 8 events

Tags: api, google-calendar-api

I have imbedded the Google Calendar (in its own web page) in my website and desire to have my home page list the next 8 events (from the Google Calendar) in a table at the bottom of my web page (above the header). The problem is that I have no experience working with Google API's.

I am only looking for direction, not the solution. I have a lot to learn and the only way to go about it is to DO it!

Thank you for your time and response in advance.

S